# Rails has_many, :through form adding variables to joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, join, nested-forms, has-many-through

I'm trying to build an app for storing recipes so that I can (eventually) build shopping lists based on recipe ingredients.

What I'm struggling with is being able to link ingredients to recipes based on their `measures`, i.e. a recipe could use *300 grams* of flour and *one pinch* of salt while another recipe might use *two cups* of flour and *one teaspoon* of salt.

I've set up the DB with three tables: `Recipes`, `Measures` and `Ingredients`. However I'm getting stuck trying to create the basic form elements so that I can associate the `unit` (e.g. grams, cups or mL) and quantity (1 or 500) with the ingredient of the measure. So, how do I put the form together to allow this?

I started the form by adding a collection of check boxes for all the available ingredients, but this only allows the ingredient to be linked or not linked - there's no way that I know to also add information about elements of the joining table to be added here.

Here's the recipes_controller:

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new

  @ingredients = Ingredient.all
end

def edit
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  @ingredients = Ingredient.all
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

  if @recipe.save
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
...
private
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :method, :category, ingredient_ids:[])
  end
```

And the models:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :measures
  has_many :ingredients, through: :measures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

class Measure < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :recipe
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :measures
  has_many :recipes, through: :measures
end
```

And the basic Recipe form partial:

```
# /views/recipes/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |form| %>     
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes :ingredient_ids, @ingredients, :id, :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.fields_for :measures do |ff| %>
      <% @ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
        <%= ff.label :unit %>
        <%= ff.text_field :unit %> | 
        <%= ff.label :quantity %>
        <%= ff.text_field :quantity %> | 
        <%= ff.label ingredient.name %>
        <%= ff.check_box :ingredient_id %>     
        <br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Thanks for your help!